# How can I access each path/filename using jquery on an <input type='file' multiple>

Tags: jquery, html

Currently I am using jQuery to read the value of a file input to read the file extension and determine if it is a zip file. (It does not matter that I get fakepath as I only need access to the filename.) When I have multiple set on the input tag and I select multiple files .val() only grabs the path of the last file that was selected. Is there any way to iterate through each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) defines a `FileList` object which is accessible through the `files` property of the event target. You could do something like this:

```
$("input[type='file']").change(function(e) {
    var fileList = e.target.files;
});
```

The `FileList` object contains a list of `File` objects, and the `name` property should give you the name you're looking for:

```
console.log(fileList[0].name);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/EmdFA/1/).

**Edit**

Previously, I showed the use of the `originalEvent` property of the jQuery event object. This was unnecessary since the `target` property is present on the jQuery event object as well as the original event object.